# Is there a way to separate two values from a return statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return

I am making an app that requires two integers from the same function to separate and be subtracted from other variables.

```py
player2overall_rate = player2overall_rate + player_2_rate
player2overall_other = player2overall_other + player_2_rate_other
return player2overall_rate, player2overall_other
```

I need a way to separate these two integers, `player2overall_rate` and `player2overall_other` so that I can compare each separately from other values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unpack the values like this:

```py
# Option 1
vals = func() # Returns tuple like (val0, val1)
val0, val1 = vals # Can unpack afterwards

# Option 2
val0, val1 = func() # Unpack at call-time
```

Either works, it depends on your specific use case

Comment: Thanks so much! this will solve my problem!